# Can you explain why support v4 and v7 on android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I was checking support library for android, but i cant understand why they divided into v4 and v7 ?

Why just don't use one support library for all versions? Or even all classes on support, be on SDK properly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> but i cant understand why they divided into v4 and v7 ?

They are not "divided into v4 and v7". They are divided along functional lines. There are many pieces of the Android Support package, such as:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

The only ones of these that are replacements for the other are `support-v4` and `support-v13`. `support-v13` contains everything that is in `support-v4`, plus a few additional classes that are only relevant for devices running API Level 13 or higher.

The `-vNN` notation in the artifact name is just to help remind you what Android API level the code in that library works back to.

> Why just dont use one support library for all versions?

For the same reason that we do not compile in every line of code ever written in human history: we don't need it. `appcompat-v7` is an independent library from `leanback-v17`, for example -- they are about as related as they are to one of my libraries.

> Or even all classes on support, be on SDK properly?

In some cases, it it because we have not invented a time machine yet, and so we cannot "retcon" older versions of Android to have different classes and methods. For example, part of the reason why `appcompat-v7` exists is to allow the action bar pattern to be used on devices going back to API Level 7; the native action bar only showed up at API Level 11.

There is also pressure from manufacturers to keep the size of the OS down, particularly framework classes, to reduce the amount of RAM and flash storage needed to build an Android device. Hence, some things (e.g., `leanback-v17`, for Android TV-style experiences) are not part of the OS as they are not needed everywhere.

Also, by having things in libraries, your app is more independent of the underlying device. For example, some developers will use the backport of fragments in `support-v4` or `support-v13`, not because they want to run on devices older than API Level 11 (when native fragments were introduced), but because they want an implementation of fragments that works the same across all Android versions. The native fragments implementation will vary by Android OS version.

Answer (score 6):

v4 is compatible all the way back to version 4 of Android.  v7 is compatible back to v7.  As the Android SDK v4 is more limited, its more difficult to port some things back to (and some things may not even be possible to port back that far, but may be possible to port to 7).  Google decided that added difficulty wasn't worth it, as v4 is just ancient (its less than 1% of active devices).

There's actually more versions than that-  v8, v11, and v13 support libraries exist, they're just less common to use.

Comment: If v4 is support back to version 4 and v7 is support back to version 7, then why is it support-v4 for v4 and appcompat-v7 for v7? why not name it as "support-v7"?

Comment: Update : Checkout the "Version Support and Package Names" section [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html)  - v4 and v7 from Support library 24.2.0  mean minimum support till API level 9.

Answer (score 2):

**v4 support library** and **v7 support library** both support **android version 2.3(API level 9)** and higher and required for backward compatibility for older devices.

**difference**

*v4* has largest set of API's than others like App component, User Interface Feature, data handling ,network connectivity and utilities.

*v7* provided specfic feature sets that can be included in your app independently.

There is also *v7 AppCompact* and *v13 SupportLbrary* :

**v7 AppCompact** - for ActionBar user interface and design . it required v4 also.

**v13 SupportLbrary** - android version 3.2(API level 13) and higher and supports fragment user interface Pattern